# Can an argument in a custom jquery function change the value of a global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, global

Please i'm a beginner in jquery and javascript. I'm trying to create a function that I will use repeatedly on a page that will basically cycle children elements placed in a container. The code looks okay to me but it does'nt work as expected when I pass a global variable as an argument on calling the function. I know there's a better way to do it and I want to know how, where I'm getting it wrong or if I should use a plugin instead. Thanks ahead.

```
//THE JAVASCRIPT
var prevIndex = 0, nextIndex = 1;//these are the global variables

var imgBox = $("#img-box");//the parent container

function changeSlides(parentName, a1, b1, classInit, classFinal){
    var parentName, 
    classInit, 
    classFinal, 
    allChildren = parentName.children(), 
    prevSlide = allChildren.eq(a1), 
    nextSlide = allChildren.eq(b1), 
    allChildrenNum = allChildren.length, 
    lastSlideIndex = allChildrenNum - 1, 
    lastSlideElem = allChildren.eq(lastSlideIndex), 
    firstSlideElem = allChildren.eq(0);

    if(b1<=lastSlideIndex){
        changeClass(prevSlide,classFinal,classInit);//this is function     changes the class of the selected element from classFinal to classInit and vice     versa
        changeClass(nextSlide,classInit,classFinal);
        a1++;
        b1++;
    }else if(b1>lastSlideIndex){
        a1 = 0;
        b1 = a1 + 1;
        changeClass(firstSlideElem, classInit, classFinal);
        changeClass(lastSlideElem, classFinal, classInit);
    };
};

function changeClass(elemName, class1, class2){
    var class1,
        class2;
    if(elemName.hasClass(class1)){
        elemName.removeClass(class1).addClass(class2);
    };
};


$("button").click(function(){
    changeSlides(imgBox,prevIndex,nextIndex,"show","hide");
});


//THE HTML
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="img-box">
            <img src="img1.jpg" class="show">
            <img src="img2.jpg" class="hide">
            <img src="img3.jpg" class="hide">
        </div>
        <button></button>
    </body>
</html>

//THE CSS
.show{opacity: 1;}
.hide{opacity: 0;}
```

Comment: You could always use plugins for this kind of thing. It depends on what you want to gain from this excercise. You can start with the code in my answer below and progress from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use multiple containers on your page, you could try with classes. Try following code:

```js
function ChangeSlidesClass(boxName, btnName) {
    this.prevIndex = 0;
    this.nextIndex = 1;
    
    this.imgBox = jQuery('#' + boxName);
    this.btnName = btnName;
    
    this.setButtonCallback();
}

ChangeSlidesClass.prototype.setButtonCallback = function() {
    var obj = this;
    
    jQuery("#" + this.btnName).click(function () {
        obj.changeSlides();
    });
};

ChangeSlidesClass.prototype.changeSlides = function() {
    var allChildren, prevSlide, nextSlide, allChildrenNum, lastSlideIndex, lastSlideElem, firstSlideElem;

    allChildren    = jQuery(this.imgBox).children();
    prevSlide      = jQuery(allChildren).eq(this.prevIndex);
    nextSlide      = jQuery(allChildren).eq(this.nextIndex);
    allChildrenNum = allChildren.length;
    lastSlideIndex = allChildrenNum - 1;
    lastSlideElem  = jQuery(allChildren).eq(lastSlideIndex);
    firstSlideElem = jQuery(allChildren).eq(0);

    if (this.nextIndex <= lastSlideIndex) {
        this.changeClass(prevSlide);
        this.changeClass(nextSlide);
        this.prevIndex++;
        this.nextIndex++;
    } else if (this.nextIndex > lastSlideIndex) {
        this.prevIndex = 0;
        this.nextIndex = 1;
        this.changeClass(firstSlideElem);
        this.changeClass(lastSlideElem);
    };
};

ChangeSlidesClass.prototype.changeClass = function(element) {
    var elementIsShown = jQuery(element).hasClass("show");

    if (elementIsShown) {
        jQuery(element).removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        jQuery(element).removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
    };
};


var changeSlides1 = new ChangeSlidesClass('img-box1', 'btn1');
var changeSlides2 = new ChangeSlidesClass('img-box2', 'btn2');
```

```css
.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
.hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="img-box1">
        <img src="img1.jpg" class="show">
        <img src="img2.jpg" class="hide">
        <img src="img3.jpg" class="hide">
    </div>
            
    <button id="btn1"></button>
    
    <div id="img-box2">
        <img src="img1.jpg" class="show">
        <img src="img2.jpg" class="hide">
        <img src="img3.jpg" class="hide">
    </div>
    <button id="btn2"></button>
</body>
```

Now I define two sets of image-boxes and buttons on the page. Then I implement a javascript-class with some (public) methods and generate a new instance of that class for each image-box/button set on the page. Binding the `click`-event is done in the constructor of the class.

You can improve this, by embracing the image-box/button combination with a `<div class="myImageChanger">...</div>` and something like `var imageChangers = new ChangesSlidesClass('myImageChanger')` to initialize every instance on your page automatically. You just need to modify the class-constructor (`function ChangeSlidesClass`) to do that.

Comment: @Guido...This is super awesome. Works perfectly. I had to read through the whole code 3 times to really grasp it...I really have a lot of reading up and practice to do. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are passing global variable as function parameters and modify them in your function. This will only change the function parameter values, not the global variables, because function arguments are treated as local variables. This is also true for your constant values `show`and `hide`, you do not need to pass them through your function arguments, just use them, where needed.

When you work with global parameters, you don't have to pass them into your function. That is the whole idea behind global parameters, they are global.

Secondly you need to use `jQuery`(or `$`) to access your elements. So, since I am not sure, what you want to achieve exactly, you can start with following code:

```js
var prevIndex, nextIndex, imgBox;

prevIndex = 0;
nextIndex = 1;
imgBox    = jQuery("#img-box");

function changeSlides() {
    var allChildren, prevSlide, nextSlide, allChildrenNum, lastSlideIndex, lastSlideElem, firstSlideElem;

    allChildren    = imgBox.children();
    prevSlide      = jQuery(allChildren).eq(prevIndex);
    nextSlide      = jQuery(allChildren).eq(nextIndex);
    allChildrenNum = allChildren.length;
    lastSlideIndex = allChildrenNum - 1;
    lastSlideElem  = jQuery(allChildren).eq(lastSlideIndex);
    firstSlideElem = jQuery(allChildren).eq(0);

    if (nextIndex <= lastSlideIndex) {
        changeClass(prevSlide);
        changeClass(nextSlide);
        prevIndex++;
        nextIndex++;
    } else if (nextIndex > lastSlideIndex) {
        prevIndex = 0;
        nextIndex = 1;
        changeClass(firstSlideElem);
        changeClass(lastSlideElem);
    };
};

function changeClass(element) {
    var elementIsShown = jQuery(element).hasClass("show");

    if (elementIsShown) {
        jQuery(element).removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        jQuery(element).removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
    };
};


$("button").click(function () {
    changeSlides();
});
```

```css
.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
.hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="img-box">
        <img src="img1.jpg" class="show">
        <img src="img2.jpg" class="hide">
        <img src="img3.jpg" class="hide">
    </div>
    <button></button>
</body>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your corrections. What if I want to use the same function (changeSlides()) for another container on the same page. Would it work since both containers would be taking their increments from prevIndex and nextIndex?...how do I go about it please?

Comment: My original intention was to write a function that could be used for as many individual containers as possible on the same page. But i'll start by adopting the corrections you made...Thanks